# ExtJS sticky south panel

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using ExtJS viewport border layout. in order to create a north, center and south region. The first issue faced is that the viewport could not display a scrollbar for its contents, so i used a panel inside the viewport and added panels inside them with the location i wanted:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    id: 'viewportContainer',
    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        align: 'center'
    },
    forceFit: 'true',
    items : [{
        layout:'anchor',
        scroll:true,
        autoScroll:true,
        region : 'center',
        xtype : 'panel',
        items : [ {
            region: 'north',
            xtype: 'panel',
            bodyStyle: {
                'background': 'none'
            },
            items: [upperPanel, messagePanel()]
        },{
            layout:'anchor',
            form: searchForm.id,
            id: 'innerBody',
            region : 'center',
            xtype : 'panel',
            items : [searchForm, gridPanel ]
        } ,{
            region: 'south',
            xtype: 'panel',
            items: [bottomPanel]
        } ]
    } ]
}
```

What i want to do  is

- stick the bottomPanel to the bottom of the page, if the other
  contents are shorter than the viewable area (clientHeight) and
- if they are taller, let the footer be located right below the innerBody section.

The current implementation places the footer right below the innerBody panel but doesn't stick to the bottom when all the contents of the page are shorter than the viewable area(clientHeight)

Any help would be highly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: Your layout is `anchor`. `region`s make sense only if `border` layout is used.

Comment: if i use border layout the vertical scrollbar (disappears even though the innerBody height is taller than the page) and the bottomPanel is always at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing the following code please check it.

Mycode:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    id: 'viewportContainer',
    layout: {
        type: 'border',
        align: 'center'
    },
    forceFit: 'true',
    items : [{
        layout:'anchor',
        scroll:true,
        autoScroll:true,
        region : 'center',
        xtype : 'panel',
        items : [ {
            region: 'north',
            xtype: 'panel',
            bodyStyle: {
                'background': 'none'
            },
            items: [upperPanel, messagePanel()]
        },{
            layout:'anchor',
            form: searchForm.id,
            id: 'innerBody',
            region : 'center',
            xtype : 'panel',
        minHeight:'540',
            items : [searchForm, gridPanel ]
        } ,{
            region: 'south',
            xtype: 'panel',
            items: [bottomPanel]
        } ]
    } ]
}
```

I'm only applying the 'minHeight' property to the'innerBody' panel. It works. Please try it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is working the same way as before. The bottomPanel is attached to the innerBody and not at the bottom of the page.